# Create PATCH request

Tags: ios, objective-c, http

I want to make an request via http.
How to create PATCH request with JSON body without external frameworks?
This code dosnt work

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"PATCH"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: jsonData];
```

Comment: Search on google for "ios create request": first response is for POST request, second one for GET request (both on stackoverflow).

Comment: @Marco Pace, i need PATCH request

Comment: Create a normal POST request and add the X-HTTP-Method-Override header with the PATCH value. This should work BUT the Patch method must be implemented by web server (not all the servers support it)

Comment: Your code seems fine for me, so far. But you didn't show how you send the request and what the response or the error was. Please show the HTTP status code or the error which you got in return.